# How can i disable a checkbox depends on datetimepicker in VB .Net?

Tags: vb.net, checkbox, datetimepicker

On VB .NET is there any way to disable a checkbox, and if there are any date time picker is selected.

When I say select a date using date time picker, the checkbox still can't disabled.

The checkbox has been checked before on the date specified, and if I choose the same date as the

checkbox that I have checked the checkbox is still enabled, how can i disable that?, can you help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure if it's what you're describing:

```
Dim SelectedDate as DateTime = MyDate 'the date in question
If DateTimePicker.value.Date = SelectedDate Then
     'The 2 dates are the same
     MyCheckbox.enabled = true
Else
     'The 2 dates are differents
     MyCheckbox.enabled = false
End If
```

Comment: Thanks Sir, its worked, i can continue my project now, thanks for your help